# how to update multiple copies of multi dimensional numpy array in an efficient way

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

**Main goal:** Suppose I have a multi-dimensional array. I also have a 0-1 index set corresponding to each column for each row. For example, If my array is `[[3,6,7,8], [1,32,45,7]]`, I will have an index set as `[[1,0,1,1], [0,0,1,1]]`. I would like to take a copy of each row of my array `n` times. Then, I'd like to increase each element whose corresponding index is equal to 1 randomly.

```
import time
import random
import numpy as np

def foo(arr, upper_bound, index_set, first_set_size, sec_set_size, limit):
    iter =0

    my_array = np.zeros((first_set_size*sec_set_size, limit)) #each row is copied |sec_set_size| times
    it =0
    for i in range(first_set_size):
        for j in range(sec_set_size):
            my_array[it] = arr[i] #copy the elements from the corresponding row
            for k in range(limit):
                if index_set[i][k]==1: #update the elements whose indices are one
                    temp = arr[i][k]   #get the current value
                    my_array[it][k]  =temp + random.randint(1,upper_bound-temp) #I use fastrand.pcg32bounded here. Update the value. 
            it +=1
    return my_array


upper_bound = 50
limit = 1000
first_set_size= 100
sec_set_size = 50
arr = np.random.randint(25, size=(first_set_size, limit)) #create an array containing integer numbers
index_set= np.array([[random.randint(0,1) for j in range(limit)] for i in range(first_set_size)]) #each elements has an index which is either 1 or 0

start_time = time.time() #measure the time taken by the function
result = foo(arr, upper_bound,index_set, first_set_size, sec_set_size, limit)
print("time taken: %s " % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Once I increase the limit and set sizes, the code takes several minutes. Is there any way that I can perform this operation faster / efficiently? I've spent quite a bit of time on this, but could not improve the speed of my implementation.

EDIT:
Suppose my initial array is:

```
[[11 23 24 17  0]
 [ 1 23 12 19  5]
 [20 15  1 17 17]
 [ 3  8  7  0 24]]
```

Also, my index set is given as;

```
[[1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1]]
```

If `sec_set_size=5`, I would like to take the copy of each row and increase the values of each element if their indices are one.

The final result should be like this;

```
[[39. 23. 24. 17. 44.]
 [50. 23. 24. 17. 27.]
 [42. 23. 24. 17. 24.]
 [45. 23. 24. 17. 11.]
 [49. 23. 24. 17. 43.]
 [23. 23. 44. 19.  5.]
 [10. 23. 37. 19.  5.]
 [14. 23. 29. 19.  5.]
 [12. 23. 22. 19.  5.]
 [ 5. 23. 15. 19.  5.]
 [36. 45. 26. 37. 17.]
 [24. 40. 35. 38. 17.]
 [34. 20. 24. 31. 17.]
 [27. 16.  9. 20. 17.]
 [37. 37.  6. 37. 17.]
 [ 3. 50.  7. 46. 47.]
 [ 3. 13.  7. 37. 44.]
 [ 3. 23.  7. 32. 29.]
 [ 3. 10.  7. 22. 41.]
 [ 3. 22.  7. 32. 41.]]
```

Comment: Don't use `iter` as a variable name, it's a built-in function.

Comment: Your example isn't clear. Given your example array please show your expected output.

Comment: @blorgon I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: The output certainly helps, but the reference implementation is what's important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy is all about vectorization. If you're using python loops, you're probably doing it wrong.

First off, all the random number generators are vectorized:

```
index_set = np.random.randint(2, size=(first_set_size, limit), dtype=bool)
```

You did it correctly on the line above.

Next, to copy rows multiple times, you can use `np.repeat`:

```
my_array = np.repeat(arr, sec_set_size, axis=0)
```

Notice that you don't need `first_set_size` at all. It's redundant with `arr.shape[0]`. You can do the same with your boolean mask to make the shapes match:

```
index_set = np.repeat(index_set, sec_set_size, axis=0)
```

Now you can update the option of `my_array` masked by `index_set` with an appropriate number of randomly generated elements:

```
my_array[index_set] += np.random.randint(1, upper_bound - my_array[index_set])
```

Your entire program reduces to about four (very fast) lines, plus some initialization:

```
def foo(arr, upper_bound, index_set, sec_set_size, limit):
    my_array = np.repeat(arr, sec_set_size, axis=0)
    index_set = np.repeat(index_set, sec_set_size, axis=0)
    my_array[index_set] += np.random.randint(1, upper_bound - my_array[index_set])
    return my_array

upper_bound = 50
limit = 1000
first_set_size= 100
sec_set_size = 50
arr = np.random.randint(25, size=(first_set_size, limit)) #create an array containing integer numbers
index_set = np.random.randint(2, size=(first_set_size, limit), dtype=bool)

start_time = time.time() #measure the time taken by the function
result = foo(arr, upper_bound, index_set, sec_set_size, limit)
print(f"time taken: {time.time() - start_time}")
```

You may want to experiment with using indices instead of a boolean mask. It will make indexing more efficient since the number of non-zero elements don't need to be recomputed twice, but on the other hand the setup is a bit more expensive:

```
def foo(arr, upper_bound, index_set, sec_set_size, limit):
    my_array = np.repeat(arr, sec_set_size, axis=0)
    r, c = np.where(index_set)
    r = (sec_set_size * r[:, None] + np.arange(sec_set_size)).ravel()
    c = np.repeat(c, sec_set_size)
    my_array[r, c] += np.random.randint(1, upper_bound - my_array[r, c])
    return my_array
```

Comment: @ball_jan. Glad it worked out. How much faster is it now? I'm on mobile, so no way to test anything.

Comment: When ````limit= 1000, first_set_size= 200, sec_set_size-  50````, your method takes 1.07 while mine takes 21.09876 :)

Comment: @ball_jan. Thanks, could you also let me know how the updated version compares? I'm hoping it's marginally faster, but no guarantee.

Comment: I'm getting an invalid syntax error, but could not figure it out. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: What does ````np.where(index_set)```` exactly do?

Comment: @ball_jan. Converts `index_set`, which is a 2D boolean array into a pair of index lists. `r` is the row numbers of each 1 in the mask, and `c` is the corresponding column number.

Comment: `(sec_set_size * r[:, None] + np.arange(sec_set_size)).ravel()` turns `r` into a column vector and adds a row of numbers zero to `sec_set_size`. This makes it into a 2D result, which increments each row by one, mapping it to new indices corresponding to the expanded rows.

Comment: @ball_jan. There were a couple of typos in the new version. Fixed now.

Comment: Have you checked this with the example arrays given in the question? When I run it I get `[31, 49, 44]` for `result[0, ~index_set[0].astype(bool)]`. Shouldn't it be `[23, 24, 17]`?

Comment: @Bill. I'm getting `array([23, 24, 17])`. Are you sure that your `index_set` is specifically of `dtype=bool`? It won't work otherwise.

Comment: @Bill. Specifically, I recommend initializing `index_set = np.random.randint(2, size=(first_set_size, limit), dtype=bool)` instead of the nested comprehension OP was using.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Since my original index matrix is just 0s and 1s, how can I use ````np.wehere```` for such an array? The reason for asking is that I read that array from a file.

Comment: @ball_jan. If it's a text file, just load it as `dtype=np.uint8` and call `.view(bool)` on it. Alternatively, you can use `.astype(bool)`, but that makes a copy of the data instead of a view. `np.where`, on the other hand, does not care what the type is. It will return the indices of any non-zero elements, whether `1` or `True`.

Comment: Great! This works. One last question, if I want to do the same operation for each false value, should I just invert the boolean array?

Comment: @ball_jan. Yes, that likely won't set you back much.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is there a way that I can use ````fastrand````  method in the same way you use ````random.randint```` in ````my_array[r, c] += np.random.randint(1, upper_bound - my_array[r, c])````? Even though the code is much faster, when I run the profiler, it spends most of the time during the random number generation. Here is the GitHub link for fastrand https://github.com/lemire/fastrand

Comment: @ball_jan. You can look into the new generator API. If fastrand can generate arrays of numbers, use that instead